# Python: How to define a class attribute's value dynamically?

Tags: python, class, dynamic

I need to set a class attribute dynamically at run time.  How can this be achieved?  There is no way that I have found to set a class attribute outside of the instance init which means that it runs each time a an instance is created. This only needs to happen one time (when the class definition is loaded).

REVISED EXAMPLE.

Ideally i need to do something like this, but it seems this is not possible:

```
# Note modules are python modules which extend the functionality of my reusable app. 
class Test():
    active_modules = Test.get_active_moduels()

    @classmethod
    def get_active_moduels(cls):
        #logic for collecting installed modules
        return installed
```

I could get the job done like this, but it seems silly and causes major problems.  If i try to access `active_modules` before a Test class is instantiated i get [] even though there are active_modules.

```
# Note modules are python modules which extend the functionality of my reusable app. 
class Test():
    active_modules = []

    def __init__ (self):
        Test.get_active_moduels()

    @classmethod
    def get_active_moduels(cls):
        if not cls.active_modules:
            #logic for collecting installed modules
            .....
            cls.active_modules = installed_modules
        else:
            return cls.active_modules
```

I could get this done by creating another registry of `active_modules`, but I would think there is a way to accomplish this within the class...

Comment: I don't see any subclassing here ...

Comment: Anyway the subclasses are already available from `Test.__subclasses__()`, maybe that can help you

Comment: unfortunately the problem is way more complex then my example leads on.  I tried to create a simple need for `active_subs = Test.get_installed_subs()` this is what i am after.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to help if you used concrete terminology.  What is a "sub"?  In any case, your code can be simplified to:

```
def compute_defaults():
    they = []
    they.append('default_1')
    they.append('default_2')
    return they

class Test():
    active_subs = compute_defaults()

    def __init__(self, sub=None):
        if sub:
            self.active_subs.append(sub)
```

Then you can use your code as you wish:

```
t1 = Test()
#active will have the installed subs.
active = t1.active_subs
```

Don't over-complicate your code with getters and setters needlessly.

Comment: ['default_1', 'default_2'] are determined dynamically at run time so this is impossible. Hence the question. How to define a class attribute's value dynamically?

Comment: The getter and setter were there to insure that the class attributes got set if they were accessed prior creating the first instance of the Test class. Other wise `t1.active_subs` would yield [], unless there was an instance created.

Comment: You can replace the literal list with executable code. I've updated the answer.  If that code can't handle your situation, then you need to explain more about your situation.

Comment: Yes, as stated in my question, "creating another registry of active_modules" is an alternative approach.  I simply am looking for a definitive answer as to if this is possible from within in the Test class. Thank you for your suggestions.